# android UI elements not appearing

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created a simple android app like the one from the google tutorial.  A button on the first activity gets text from a text field...and then loads a second activity with the text that was entered on the first.

All I am trying to do is add some simple UI elements to the second activity.  In the xml I  have added a button, and I can see it perfectly well in the graphical xml viewer, but when I actually launch the app the screen is empty.

and before you suggest it... I have tried both this

`<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:text="Button" />`

and this

`<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:text="Button" />`

and neither seems to make any sort of a difference.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

xml below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SecondScreen" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);





        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);








    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: show all the xml layout plx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm submitting another answer because my first one was hardly an answer. With your code it's easy to spot the problem.

You're creating a new `View` called `textView` and then setting your entire activity's layout to be only that `TextView` with the `setContentView(textView)`. Leave that out, and instead of doing your text view in that way, refer to its id that you assigned in the layout. So do something like

```
TextView textBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textBox.setTextSize(40);
textBox.setText(message);
```

That *should* solve your problems.

As a side note, I wouldn't recommend using the `intent.getStringExtra` and I would instead use some static method `public static getMessage()` in your first activity to return a `private static String message` variable that you assign and determine in your first activity. In your second activity you would then call the method by doing something like `String message = Class1Name.getMessage()`. These shouldn't be the source of your problem though, and since I don't really know the specifics of what you're doing, I can't say for sure whether doing it this way would even work. But anyways, I can almost guarantee that getting rid of `setContentView(textView)` will make your button show up properly.

Comment: yes that did it!  Someone should mention this to google... as I essentially copy and pasted this from their website http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Yeah, as far as actually teaching you how to go and build your own app that seems...well...not particularly helpful. The main difference is that they didn't care about anything being in the second activity, so they could just set the entire `View` for it to be the `TextView` with no repercussions, because that's literally all they wanted to display. However, if you're going to have multiple items on the page, then you have to set the `contentView` as the layout, and refer to individual elements by their ID. Good luck with your Android adventures!

Comment: yeah it just seems like a bad practice to set anything to take up the whole page especially for a sample project which people are most likely going to be building upon..  Thanks though... startling to tackle it after getting well versed in iOS

Answer (score 0):

have you added `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);`in your `onCreate(..)` method?

Comment: yes right after the
    `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: you have a relative layout and set `    android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar1"` but you dont have an element with id ratingBar1

Comment: I removed that and it doesnt make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Check if ur orientation of layout is vertical and if still not helps the post ur complete xml here someone can here

Comment: in the graphical editor the orientation is vertical, however in the xml itself I don't see any statements about orientation

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an "answer" per se, but there might be two things. It could be that the android device your emulator is based off of has a different pixel density than the one in the XML viewer, and thus shoves your button off the bottom of the screen due to the `marginTop`, you could try getting rid of the margin and see if that shows up. If that doesn't help, please put your second activity's (`SecondScreen`) code up, as the XML looks like it should be working fine.

Comment: I tried making the margin be 0 and also removing the line completely and neither had an effect.  I have added the code above